# Blank bitmap generated from Webview in Android

Tags: java, android, webview, bitmap

I am trying to generate bitmaps from webpage in webview. 
I am able to get bitmap of visible screen only and not able to get bitmaps of rest of the screen.
So, I am manually scrolling down screen and taking bitmap again but, at this time generated bitmap is blank.

Here is my code I am using:

```
 try {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webview.getWidth(), webview.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
//            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webview.getDrawingCache());
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            webview.draw(canvas);

            String GVCode = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/WebToPDF");
            myDir.mkdirs();

            String fname = GVCode + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists()) file.delete();

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            Document document = new Document();
            String input = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/WebToPDF/" + GVCode + ".jpg";
            String output = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/WebToPDF/" + GVCode + ".pdf";
            String stringPrintDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/WebToPDF/";

            File myDirPdf = new File(stringPrintDirectory);
            if (!myDirPdf.exists()) {
                myDirPdf.mkdirs();
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
            writer.open();
            document.open();
            Image img = Image.getInstance(input);
            document.setPageSize(img);
            document.newPage();
            img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            document.add(img);
            document.close();
            writer.close();
            LogShowHide.LogShowHideMethod("+++ : ", "Bitmap is Done.");

            webview.scrollTo(0, height);
            height = height + height;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If anyone can figure out where I am making mistakes, it will help me a alot...

Feel free to ask more information, if required.

Comment: You might try adding a slight delay after scrolling before doing the `draw()`s on the remainder of the page. Oh, and check your logic here: `height = height + height;`.

Comment: But, generated bitmap in upper part is blank printed... only visible part capture

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for your interest. Issue is in some devices are like when I create first bitmap it's coming properly, then I scroll down to create second bitmap, now the generated bitmap is having total height of two bitmaps and in that whole bitmap first section is empty and at bottom I am getting bitmap. These is continuing for the all the pages.                                                               Let's say I am having five pages to scroll then while creating last bitmap I am getting first four blank bitmap and at the bottom of generated bitmap it's showing me last page's bitmap.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. I thought you meant the bottom portion of the page was blank.

Comment: No, Top portion is blank, bottom portion in getting the contents only,

Answer (score 0):

call [WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()) before create webview

Comment: Appreciate your effort but please highlight the points along with the answer link since the pointed URL or the content of the link may change in future which will be misleading.